# Why do some elements remain even if the condition matches for each one?

Tags: ruby

I have created a small store application in Ruby. The concept is simple: I want to be able to add, remove, and view the 'database' in this example. The code seems to work; however, it does not behave like one would expect. I can add any product just fine, but when I try to remove them by a certain criterion that matches each item, only some are removed.

```
class Store
  PRODUCT = Struct.new(:identifier, :parameters)

  def initialize(database = [])
    @database = database
  end

  def increment
    # Increment the unique identifier if the database is not empty
    # Otherwise, set the initial value for the unique identifier
    @database.any? ? @database.map { |object| object[:identifier] }.max + 1 : 1
  end

  def add(product)
    @database.push(identifier: increment, parameters: product)
  end

  def remove(product)
    @database.each do |object|
      product.each do |key, value|
        @database.delete(object) if object[key] == value
        @database.delete(object) if object[:parameters][key] == value
      end
    end
  end

  def view
    puts @database
    puts "\n"
  end
end

store = Store.new

store.add(name: 'Fanta', volume: 33, unit: 'centiliter', count: 48, price: 9.95, currency: 'SEK')
store.add(name: 'Sprite', volume: 33, unit: 'centiliter', count: 48, price: 9.95, currency: 'SEK')
store.add(name: 'Coca-Cola', volume: 33, unit: 'centiliter', count: 48, price: 9.95, currency: 'SEK')

store.view

store.remove(price: 9.95)

store.view
```

This example will add three arbitrary items to the `Store` instance and list the contents found in the `@database` array. This array will of course hold the values:

```
{:identifier=>1, :parameters=>{:name=>"Fanta", :volume=>33, :unit=>"centiliter", :count=>48, :price=>9.95, :currency=>"SEK"}}
{:identifier=>2, :parameters=>{:name=>"Sprite", :volume=>33, :unit=>"centiliter", :count=>48, :price=>9.95, :currency=>"SEK"}}
{:identifier=>3, :parameters=>{:name=>"Coca-Cola", :volume=>33, :unit=>"centiliter", :count=>48, :price=>9.95, :currency=>"SEK"}}
```

The code then proceeds to remove any product with a price of 9.95, which should match all the products in the `@database` array. However, when I list its contents once more, one product remains:

```
{:identifier=>2, :parameters=>{:name=>"Sprite", :volume=>33, :unit=>"centiliter", :count=>48, :price=>9.95, :currency=>"SEK"}}
```

I cannot find any logic to this. Why does my `remove` method not remove all the elements if the condition holds true for each comparison?

Comment: If you will add some more products to your store, for example, more 3, `store.view` will print items with identifiers = 2,4,6. It seems that your `@database` is looping only odd elements when you try to remove with number parameters. If you will try to `store.remove(name: "Sprite")` - it's will works correctly. Why - I don't know. If I will find an answer - I will post it)

Comment: You are correct! Although, just like you, I have no idea why this would occur in the code I have produced. Perhaps, someone could explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on following looping,

```
@database.each do |object|
  product.each do |key, value|
    puts '-----------------'
    @database.delete(object) if object[key] == value
    @database.delete(object) if object[:parameters][key] == value
  end
end
```

It is assumed to run 3 iteration on each loop for `@database`,

**first iteration** - it delete first with identifier = 1 for each loop counter 0

**second iteration** - it get modified `@database` as first get deleted, second become first and 3rd become 2nd and counter of each loop is at 1. So it delete new 2nd element of `@database` having identifier = 3.

**third iteration** - It will have each loop counter at 2 and new updated `@database` will have only 1 element having identifier = 2 (rescued in 2nd iteration) and there is no third element to proceed iteration further so nothing is iterated.

**Correction needed:**

```
def remove(product)
  @database.reject! do |object|
    product.map do |k,v|
      object[k] == v if object.has_key?(k)
      object[:parameters][k] == v if object[:parameters].has_key?(k)
    end.inject(&:|)
  end
end
```

Comment: You are correct! It looks like I broke the iterator as I removed elements each time I went through the array. Thank you for the proposed solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem comes from float comparison. There are many ways to approach this. One of them:

```
  def remove(product)
    @database.delete_if do |object|
      product.any? do |key, value|
        matches?(object[key], value) || matches?(object[:parameters][key], value)
      end
    end
  end

  def matches?(obj1, obj2)
    if obj1.is_a?(Float) || obj2.is_a?(Float)
      (obj1-obj2).abs < 0.001
    else
      obj1 == obj2
    end
  end
```

Comment: Nope problem do not come from float comparison.Edit answer to explain what he did wrong in it, not to provide alternate.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, as `store.remove(currency: 'SEK')` produces the same inconsistency. Therefore, I think my logic is somehow flawed beyond a single parameter.